# Onsen UI: Contact Us Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm creating a mobile app using onsen-ui framework and phonegap. I want to add an In-App "contact us" form, where a user can submit a form and on successful submission the form will be sent to email@domain.com.

In index.html I added

```
<script type="text/ons-template" id="contact.html"> 
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="sNavigator"> 
<ons-page id="page-contact">
   <ons-toolbar>     

    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button onclick="setHome();">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-left"></ons-icon>
     </ons-toolbar-button>        
    </div> 

    <div class="center white">
    <span id="search-text" class="trn" data-trn-key="contact">Contact Us</span>
    </div>                  
   </ons-toolbar>

    <div class="home-header">
      <img src="css/images/banner.png" alt="" title="">
      <p class="center trn" data-trn-key="contact">We respond to messages in the order received</p>
    </div>   

   <form id="frm-contact" class="frm-contact" method="post">

   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="first_name"  class="first_name text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="First Name" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="last_name"  class="last_name text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Last Name" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="number" name="contact_phone"  class="contact_phone text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Mobile Phone" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="email" name="email_address"  class="email_address text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Email address" value="" data-validation="email" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="subject"  class="subject text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Subject" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <textarea style="width:100%;height:80px" name="message"  class="message text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Your Message" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" ></textarea>
      </div>

      <p class="small-font-dim trn" data-trn-key="create_account_terms">
      Please note all fields are mandatory, you should fill in all before submission.</p>      
   </div>

   <button class="button green-btn button--large trn" onclick="contact();" data-trn-key="contact" >
    Submit Now!
    <div class="search-btn"><ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-right"></ons-icon></div>
   </button>
   </form>

</ons-page>
</ons-navigator> 
</script>
```

Then I'm validating the form in the .js file and calling the API function

```
    case "page-contact":         
     translatePage();
     translateValidationForm();
     $(".full_name").attr("placeholder",  getTrans("Full Name",'full_name') );
     $(".last_name").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Last Name','last_name') );
     $(".contact_phone").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Mobile Phone','contact_phone') );
     $(".email_address").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Email address','email_address') );
     $(".subject").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Subject','subject') );
     $(".message").attr("placeholder",  getTrans('Your Message','message') );        

     break;
```

Here I'm doing the validation and calling the API from the webserver:

```
function contact()
{
    $.validate({    
        form : '#frm-contact',    
        borderColorOnError:"#FF0000",
        onError : function() {      
        },      
        onSuccess : function() {              
          var params = $( "#frm-contact").serialize();        
          params+="&device_id="+ getStorage("device_id");
          callAjax("contact",params);       
          return false;
        }  
    });
}
```

At the webserver end the PHP code includes

```
    public function actionContact($to='',$from='',$subject='',$body='')
    {                
        $from1=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('global_admin_sender_email');
        if (!empty($from1)){
            $from=$from1;
        }       

        $email_provider=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('email_provider');

        if ( $email_provider=="smtp"){
            $smtp_host=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_host');
            $smtp_port=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_port');
            $smtp_username=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_username');
            $smtp_password=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('smtp_password');

            $mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;

            Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Host=$smtp_host;
            Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Username=$smtp_username;
            Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Password=$smtp_password;
            Yii::app()->Smtpmail->Port=$smtp_port;

            $mail->SetFrom($from, '');
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            $mail->AddAddress($to, "");
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
                //echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                return false;
            }else {
                //echo "Message sent!";
                return true;
            }                       
        } elseif ( $email_provider=="mandrill"){
            $api_key=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('mandrill_api_key');         
            try {
                 require_once 'mandrillapp/Mandrill.php';
                 $mandrill = new Mandrill($api_key);
                 $message = array(
                    'html' => $body,
                    'text' => '',
                    'subject' => $subject,
                    'from_email' => $from,
                    //'from_name' => 'Example Name',
                    'to' => array(
                        array(
                            'email' => $to,
                            //'name' => 'Recipient Name',
                            'type' => 'to'
                        )
                    )
                );                
                $async = false;
                $ip_pool = '';
                $send_at = '';
                $result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
                //dump($result);
                if (is_array($result) && count($result)>=1){
                    if ($result[0]['status']=="sent"){
                        return true;
                    }                       
                } 
            } catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {
                //echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();

            }   
            return false;
        }

        $body = $_POST['first_name']. ' ' .$_POST['last_name']. ' ' .$_POST['contact_phone']. ' ' .$_POST['message'];

        $to       = 'info@domain.com';
        $from     = $_POST['email_address'];

        $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";      
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message =<<<EOF
$body
EOF;

        if (!empty($to)) {
            if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The form is sending the email, however if there is no/null data I can't get the information submitted.

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Place this:  `console.log(params);` before this: `callAjax("contact",params);` and post the results.  I am curious to see if serialize is getting everything and what it is.

Comment: @Munsterlander thanks for the comment and sorry for the late reply. I didn't working nothing. I received an email with no subject and no sender and no body at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you posted, there was an error regarding the device ID.  Specifically, the function getStorage was undefined.  The code posted below works fine and was able to send all the fields via post to my test PHP page and send an email.  Granted, I didn't use a complex PHP processor as you have, but it works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300italic,300,400italic,500,700,700italic,500italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Onsen UI 2.0 Quickstart</title>

    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        function contact()
        {
            var params = $( "#frm-contact").serialize();    
            console.log(params);
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
 <ons-page id="page-contact">
   <ons-toolbar>     

    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button onclick="setHome();">
        <ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-left"></ons-icon>
     </ons-toolbar-button>        
    </div> 

    <div class="center white">
    <span id="search-text" class="trn" data-trn-key="contact">Contact Us</span>
    </div>                  
   </ons-toolbar>

    <div class="home-header">
      <img src="css/images/banner.png" alt="" title="">
      <p class="center trn" data-trn-key="contact">We respond to messages in the order received</p>
    </div>   

   <form id="frm-contact" class="frm-contact" method="post">

   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="first_name"  class="first_name text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="First Name" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="last_name"  class="last_name text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Last Name" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="number" name="contact_phone"  class="contact_phone text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Mobile Phone" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="email" name="email_address"  class="email_address text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Email address" value="" data-validation="email" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <input type="text" name="subject"  class="subject text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Subject" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" >
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrapper">
      <textarea style="width:100%;height:80px" name="message"  class="message text-input text-input--underbar has_validation" 
      placeholder="Your Message" value="" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="this field is mandatory!" ></textarea>
      </div>

      <p class="small-font-dim trn" data-trn-key="create_account_terms">
      Please note all fields are mandatory, you should fill in all before submission.</p>      
   </div>

   <button class="button green-btn button--large trn" onclick="contact();" data-trn-key="contact" >
    Submit Now!
    <div class="search-btn"><ons-icon icon="fa-chevron-right"></ons-icon></div>
   </button>
   </form>

</ons-page>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    $to = 'test@test.com'; 
    $from = $_REQUEST['email_address']; 
    $message = $_REQUEST['message']; 
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject']; 
    $header = "From: <".$email_address.">" ."\r\n";
    $send = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $header); 
    if(!$send){ 
        die(); 
    }
?>
```

Also, do note that I didn't send your other fields [first_name, last_name, contact_phone] but they can be added anywhere.  Lastly, this is by no means a secure method of sending mail, but something thrown together to prove that Onsen does not interfere with the sending of mail via an HTML form with jQuery.

Edit:  Although this is branching from the actual question, based on your comments, I would highly recommend reading some of these:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19365/is-this-a-secure-and-best-practice-php-mail-function

[Secure php email script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606307/secure-php-email-script)

[What is the best way to send a secure email in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187738/what-is-the-best-way-to-send-a-secure-email-in-php)

Comment: Thanks I've resolved the issue, but please can you clarify what you said it's not a secure method of sending mail? Will spammers be able to use the form to send bulk spam emails?

Comment: Well, the php file I posted - as an example - is extremely unsecure because it will accept any $_REQUEST to it and send out an email.  So this "could" become a spam portal which would result in your IP / mail server getting blacklisted.  There are tons of great secure mail scripts out there, but at a minimum you need to confirm the request is coming from your server and not a remote address as well as validate the input / sanitize the input to prevent injection attacks.

Comment: So based on your example I changed the $_POST to $_REQUEST as you're mentioning this is considered insecure. I'm using the onsen ui and js validation within the mobile app itself which will be connected to API file on server to send the email to corresponded receiver thus as far as I understood this might be risky. Regarding the scripts all of them are using $_POST and tried them as stand-alone they're working fine but using the in-app nothing is posted.

Comment: $_REQUEST just simply contains $_POST, $_GET, and $_COOKIE.  It is often a quick method, when you are developing your server side processing.  The security is not solely in the app itself and you should do client side validation as well as server side validation.  What you do need to do, is server side security.  This could be passing a secure token with the request or such.  You just want to make sure that someone can't abuse your mailer from outside your app.

Comment: It turns to be $_GET and not $_REQUEST I should've remember that my mistake. The token has been already added but when it was failing to send I thought the token is the reasons so I removed it I'll re-add it now again.

Comment: 1 thing I'm still getting is "Network error has occurred please try again!" do you think it's API connection issue?

Comment: On what event and how is the error returned, JS or PHP?

Comment: On submission and it's JS most probably not PHP because PHP is passing the parameters and executing the function

Answer (score 0):

For GOOGLERS:
Thanks to @munsterlander I was able to resolve the issue by replacing the `$_POST` to `$_GET` which helped doing the whole process in the way needed.

```
$body = $_GET['first_name']. ' ' .$_GET['last_name']. ' ' .$_GET['contact_phone']. ' ' .$_GET['message'];

        $to       = 'info@domain.com';
        $from     = $_GET['email_address'];

        $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";      
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
        $subject = $_GET['subject'];
$message =<<<EOF
$body
EOF;
```